# ERROR ReferenceError: OktaSignIn is not defined

Tags: angular, angular2-services, webpack-2, okta, okta-api

I am trying to integrate okta with webpack and angular2, I am using almost everything correctly and I end up with error.
I am using setup from https://angular.io/resources/zips/webpack/webpack.zip as it is and also followed things correctly mentioned at http://developer.okta.com/blog/2017/03/27/angular-okta-sign-in-widget

i tried to import okta-sign-in.min.js
in vendor.ts as well in okta.service.ts
with

```js
import '@okta/okta-signin-widget/dist/js/okta-sign-in.min';
```

file gets imported but still i get OktaSignIn is not defined error

[image]

Thanks for any help in advance..

Comment: Why did you used obfuscated libraries as sources?

Answer (score 2):

You definitely not following the steps. 
There's no significance of this line at all.

```
import '@okta/okta-signin-widget/dist/js/okta-sign-in.min';
```

okta-sign-in.min is a javascript which needs to be included either in index.html.
If you are using angular-cli, then as mentioned in tutorial

```
"scripts": [
  "../node_modules/@okta/okta-signin-widget/dist/js/okta-sign-in.min.js"
],
```

All steps in tutorial are correctly mentioned.

Step 1: Create 1 service

```
declare let OktaSignIn: any;
```

This line will be needed, intialize the constructor here as per need.

Step 2: calling this service in whatevercomponent.component.ts.

Comment: i guess u will be able to load it via some webpack plugins. here is one of the module https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin . Post your webpack config.

Comment: since i am using webpack can not directly include script in index file and i am not using angular-cli hence no place to add `"scripts": [
  "../node_modules/@okta/okta-signin-widget/dist/js/okta-sign-in.min.js"
],` and `import '@okta/okta-signin-widget/dist/js/okta-sign-in.min'`
is for importing library which does the job correctly

Comment: no that import wont work because okta-sign-in.min doesnt export anything. its a JS

Comment: in one of my other service in same project i used `import 'aws-sdk/dist/aws-sdk';
declare const AWS: any;` it worked. i believe even aws-sdk is a js which does not export anything, its a way to import entire module without importing any member, since there is no `from`. i got one temporary fix  http://stackoverflow.com/a/43653618/3964895

Comment: probably its typings would have been present.!! you can import only if those modules are exported.

Answer (score 0):

```html
step1
import '@okta/okta-signin-widget/dist/js/okta-sign-in.min';
step2:
"scripts": [
  "../node_modules/@okta/okta-signin-widget/dist/js/okta-sign-in.min.js"
],
step3:
declare let OktaSignIn: any;
step4:
var Oktasignin=new Oktasignin('okta-signin-widget');
```

Answer (score 0):

replaced

```
declare let OktaSignIn: any;
import '@okta/okta-signin-widget/dist/js/okta-sign-in.min';
```

by

```
var OktaSignIn = require('@okta/okta-signin-widget');
```

just read somewhere it happens because of tslint not webpack

Answer (score 0):

This requires a combination of correct typings and correct library integration. Okta unfortunately doesn't make this easy or clear in their docs or library maintainer responses to issues on their Github repository.

[@parth-ghiya was most of the way there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43627270/939634) but his approach lacks typing support.

Here are my typings so that I can use the widget as a global (ambient) type.

```js
declare class OktaSignIn {
  constructor(configuration: OktaSignInConfig);
}

interface OktaSignIn {
  renderEl(configuration: { el: string }): void;
  remove(): void;

  session: {
    get: (callback: (repsonse: any) => void) => void;
  };
}

interface OktaSignInConfigAuthParams {
  issuer: string;
  display: 'page';
  scopes: string[];
  responseType: string[];
}

interface OktaSignInConfigi18n {
  en: {
    'primaryauth.username.placeholder': string;
    'primaryauth.username.tooltip': string;
    'error.username.required': string;
    'error.password.required': string;
  };
}

interface OktaSignInConfig {
  baseUrl: string;
  logo: string;
  clientId?: string;
  redirectUri?: string;
  authParams: OktaSignInConfigAuthParams;
  i18n: OktaSignInConfigi18n;
}
```